# Convert text data type to date

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-workbench

I am working on a database about global COVID-19 vaccinations. In this database, there's a column named date with text data type and the date is in the format **mm/dd/yyyy**.
I have tried to use `str_to_date()`, `date_format()` or `date()` to convert the column to date data type in the SELECT query but it only works for the format **yyyy/mm/dd**.
May I ask how to convert this date column, with this format **mm/dd/yyyy** to date for SELECT query use, without the need to ALTER TABLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in MySQL function you are looking for is [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).  You can pass this function a string containing a date, in a specified format, and it will return a datetime value.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format for format specifiers.

example:

```
select str_to_date('08/28/2021', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

returns:

```
2021-08-28
```